# Find $P(A \cap B)$ given $P(A) = .55, P(B) = .45$, and $P(A' \cup B') = .85$

Tags: probability

> Find $P(A \cap B)$ given $P(A) = .55, P(B) = .45,$ and $P(A' \cup B') = .85$

I am having trouble finding the $P(A \cap B)$ because I don't know how to rewrite $P(A' \cup B')$ or what formula to use. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint: de Morgan's Rule for Set Complements.

Comment: $P(A \cap B)=1-P(\neg(A \cap B))=1-P(\neg A \cup \neg B))=1-0.85=0.15$

Comment: No need for $P(A)$ and $P(B)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $P(A\cap B) = P(\overline{\bar A \cup \bar B})= 1-P(\bar A\cup \bar B)$. Thus, we can easily find the answer as $$P(A\cap B) = 1-0.85 =0.15.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $P((A'\cup B')')=P(A\cap B)$. So the probability is just.. 0.15.

thx to Graham Kemp for correcting this :P

---

INCORRECT STUFF BELOW

Assuming that $P(A\cup B)=1$ (otherwise there's no way to do it), then use $P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)$. So we would also have $P(A'\cup B')=P(A')+P(B')-P(A'\cap B')$.

So the answer would be...

---

.

.

.

$P(A\cap B)$=0.05. I think.

Comment: No need to assume that (in fact, the question explicitly states otherwise).

Comment: I'm not sure where, but technically you're right anyway.

Comment: The original post had complements.

Comment: In the title (after you changed it from $P(\neg A \cup \neg B)=0.85$ to $P(A \cup B)=0.85$).

Comment: Oh! I thought the ' signs were accidental. Fixed.

Comment: @GrahamKemp: Yes, see my comment above. In any case, no need to assume that $P(A \cup B)=1$.

Comment: And hmmm... your answer does not offer any solution due to the fact that $P(A \cup B)$ is not given (which is probably why you were down-voted).

Comment: yeah i pretty much screwed everything up :\